# Gravity simulation going haywire

Tags: processing

I'm currently working on a Processing sketch featuring a very basic gravity simulation (based on an example given in Daniel Schiffman's book Learning Processing) but my gravity keeps behaving in a bizarre way and I'm at a loss to know what to do about it. Here's the simplest example I can come up with:

```
float x = 50;
float y = 50;

float speed = 2;
float gravity = 0.1;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  fill(175);
  stroke(0);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);

  y = y + speed;
  speed = speed + gravity;

//Dampening bounce effect when the ball hits bottom
  if (y > height) {
    speed = speed * -0.95;
  }
}
```

The above is virtually identical to what's in Schiffman's book aside from a different starting speed and a different window size. It seems to work fine for the first two bounces but on the third bounce the ball becomes stuck to the bottom of the window.

I have no idea where to even begin trying to debug this. Can anyone give any pointers?

Comment: After it hits  the bottom, try changing y so that it is "in bounds"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `y` remains greater than `height`, your code just keeps flipping the `speed` over and over without giving the ball a chance to bounce. You want the ball to move away from the boundary whenever it is at or past the boundary.

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course. I'm slapping my forehead now. A simple `y = height;` after the bounce does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Setting y to height in the (if y > height) block helps, but the ball never comes to 'rest' (sit on the bottom line when done).  
There are two problems with Shiffman's example 5.9 which is where you probably started: 
1) y can become greater than (height + speed), which makes it seem to go thud on the ground or bounce wildly
  -- fixed with the suggestion
2) The algorithm to update y does things in the wrong order, so the ball never comes to rest 
Correct order is:

- if it is time to 'bounce

  - negate speed including dampening (* 0.95)
  - set y to location of the 'ground'
- Add gravity to speed
- Add speed to y

This way, when it is time to bounce (y is > height), and speed is positive (going downward):
   speed is set to negative (times dampening)
   y is set to height
   speed is set less negative by the gravity factor
   y is made less positive by adding the (still negative) speed

In my example, I didn't want the object to disappear so I use a variable named 'limit' to be the lowest (most positive y) location for the center of the object.

```
float x = 50;
float y = 50;

float speed = 2;
float gravity = 0.1;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  y = height - 20;  
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  fill(175);
  stroke(0);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);

  float limit = height - (speed + 5);

//Dampening bounce effect when the ball hits bottom
  if (y > limit) {
    speed = speed * -0.95;
    y = limit;
  }
  speed = speed + gravity;
  y = y + speed;
}
```